# Trying to upload an image in php and a permission denial arises at the move_uploaded_file() function

Tags: php

My code gets a permission denied error at the move_uploaded_file() function when I'm trying to save a file into a folder on my server (from the temp folder).

My user has full permissions across all the website directories and files. Is there an apache user that need permissions as well? How do I give permissions to this apache user?

If that isn't the case. Is there a way I can use the php chmod function to fix this problem?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  The folder you need to move the file to doesn't need *you* to have permissions, it needs for the web server to have permissions.

Basically you need to figure out what account your web server is running as and give that user write permissions to the destination directory.

To figure out what your web server account name is, try the following command (assuming you're running Linux):

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:80
```

You should get back a bunch of lines with a USER column.  One will be root, ignore that one.  The other user listed is the user under which your web server is running.  It's probably something like www or www-data or apache or the like.

After that, navigate to the parent directory of your upload directory and change it's ownership and permissions with the following command:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data uploads
sudo chmod u+w uploads
```

At that point, your webserver user now has access to write to your uploads directory.  If you have any trouble, post a comment and I'll try to help out.

Comment: Incidentally, I would *highly* suggest that you have your uploads directory outside of your document root.  In other words, if your document root is /var/www (typical setup on Linux-based servers), your uploads directory might be something like /var/uploads.  Also, it's a best security practice to *not* give your web server user write access to directories it doesn't need write access to.  If your dynamic content will be generated by a database for example, and the code behind your site doesn't change, your whole /var/www directory can probably safely be read-only by your web user account.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you gave the folder 777 permissions? The folder needs those permission.

Comment: No, do NOT do that, it's a security risk.  Filling out more info below.

Comment: He didn't say it needed to be secure. I've had plenty of applications where giving a folder 777 permissions results fine.

Comment: If you had suggested that he do this just as a quick-and-dirty test and immediately set the correct ownership/permissions after validating that that works, I might have agreed.  There's no reason he or she shouldn't just set the correct permissions from the start.  It's not any harder, and will prevent the OP from later having to unlearn an excruciatingly bad practice.